# Enumerating through a file in Python, not looking at entire file for some reason?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, enumerate

I am trying to make a game in pygame and I want to read the map from a text file that looks like:
..........\n..........\n..........

and so on.

```
tile = load_image("/Users/hunsaker12/Dropbox/GameDesign/Assets/grass1.png")
    #loop through map text document, some shits goin on
    mapFile = open(os.path.join("/Users/hunsaker12/Dropbox/GameDesign/Assets/map1.rtf"), 'r')
    mapInfo = mapFile.read().splitlines()
    for roomrow, keys in enumerate(mapInfo):
        for roomcol, letter in enumerate(keys):
            if letter == '.':
                newTile = tile
                window.blit(newTile, (roomcol * 64, roomrow * 64))
```

for some reason its not looking at the whole file I think, and it seems to be repeating certain sections. I am new to python.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And, when i print out what the rows and columns are it starts at column = 30 and row = 7. but my file is a 10 X 10 square of periods. So thats confusing me. why doesnt it start at 0,0? and why does it go so high?

Comment: If you add a `print(roomcol)` in the `for roomcol, letter in enumerate(keys):` loop it starts with 30?

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes

Comment: Calling `os.path.join()` with only one parameter is bizarre - what is that supposed to be accomplishing?

Comment: The map file is *rich-text*. Is that what you want? Is there any formatting information in the file that you don't expect?

Comment: @bnaecker I changed the file to a .txt and that fixed the weird large indexes! Thanks! But, now it is looking at all the rows, but only three columns (7, 8 and 9) over and over again